How to segregate debug/release Firebase Crashlytics data from android application
My organisation has recenlty implemented Firebase Crashlytics and Google Analytics into one of their Android applications.
We wish segregate the Crashlytics/Analytics data for debug and release versions (with other possible versions to be added in the future e.g. free and paid versions).
the issue we have is that we cannot achieve this by simply using different application package names as the android application in question employs an number of paid for sdks whose licences are associated with the package name. this results in either the sdk in question not working at all or working with reduced functionality.
does firebase crashlytics/analytics support a configuration option that would allow us to keep crash/analytics data segregated on something other than the package name of the application?
